# Empty cell on a column with other multiple columns condition to be updated with date from another column plus dateoffset(7)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Trying to update an empty cell from particular column with multiple other columns condition with another column's date + dateoffset(7).

```
A       B                C                 D    E   F
38  16-07-2018 14:26    NaN               99    44  60
213 22-06-2018 12:43    NaN               94    65  60
43  23-06-2018 05:36    NaN              102    49  60
51  17-06-2018 21:19    NaN               35    111 60
57  05-06-2018 16:15    10-06-2018 13:16   23   22  60
209 01-06-2018 17:46    06-06-2018 17:58   67   64  55
```

`df['C'][(df['E']>30) & (df[d'D']>90) & (df['D']<150) & (df['F']==60) & (df['C'].isnull())]=pf.to_datetime(df['B'])[(df['E']>30) & (df[d'D']>90) & (df['D']<150) & (df['F']==60) & (df['C'].isnull())] + pd.DateOffset(days=7)`

output is giving me odd epoch time

```
A       B                C                    D  E    F
38  2018-07-16 14:26:00  1532355960000000000  99 44  60
213 2018-06-22 12:43:00  1530276180000000000  94 65  60
43  2018-06-23 05:36:00  1530336960000000000  102 49 60
51  2018-06-17 21:19:00  NaN                   35 111 60
57  2018-05-06 16:15:00  10-06-2018 13:16      23 22  60
209 2018-01-06 17:46:00  06-06-2018 17:58      67 64  55
```

Expected output is

```
A       B                C                 D    E   F
38  16-07-2018 14:26    23-07-2018 14:26   99   44  60
213 22-06-2018 12:43    29-06-2018 12:43   94   65  60
43  23-06-2018 05:36    30-06-2018 05:36   102  49  60
51  17-06-2018 21:19    NaN                35   111 60
57  05-06-2018 16:15    10-06-2018 13:16   23   22  60
209 01-06-2018 17:46    06-06-2018 17:58   67   64  55
```

Comment: Condition1 on condition2 with condition3 plus condition4. Maybe you'd like to ask a question? (Preferably on a summary problem?) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve